Snap apps start from terminal but not from KDE plasma launcher
I'm running an old kubuntu install that I upgraded to 24.04 a couple of months ago.
I've noticed that snap based apps (thunderbird, firefox, and discord, the first two installed through the standard kubuntu snaps) are shown in the launcher but won't run from there. They run fine from the command line, including if I type the exact command that launcher is using. If I run them from the command line, they sometimes, but not always, work from the launcher afterwards in the same session.
To dig deeper I tried starting firefox, and then running journalctl | grep firefox which shows the following error, that I tried googling.
/user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-firefox_firefox-010d173e106a474984043282d014298d.scope is not a snap cgroup

Based on my googling, I then added DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus (which is set in my terminal) to a number of the apps using kmenuedit. That seemed to fix it, then it stopped working again (which I think just means there was some intermittency about the whole issue).
Can anybody suggest a solution / further path of investigation? I'm very puzzled, though just running snap apps from the terminal does work.

Were you able to figure this out? I'm running into the same problem. If I check "run in terminal" in the advanced settings in kmenuedit I can get snaps to run, but otherwise they fail with the same logging you're seeing.

I gave up. The apps run absolutely fine from the command line, but not from the menu (though thanks for the "run in terminal" suggestion - I had missed that and it works).
For discord, I uninstalled and reinstalled from a deb, and for the others I just suck it up and run from terminal.
